# #1442 - Can't update table '*' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I'm really bad at SQL, but I'm trying to keep my database simple and minimalistic as possible. Not duplicating values but using references and id's instead.

Now after inserting a query I get error

> 1442 - Can't update table 'signed' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Query can be inserted when the trigger is disabled. But my query is only reading from table 'users' so there should not be a conflict. I read something about deadlock - the query is locking table while using it or something like that and therefore a trigger cannot update a row? Ideas how could I achieve this?

I simplified my query so only important things are there.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO signed (time_of_start, player)
    SELECT time_of_game_id, users.user_id 
    FROM time_of_game, users
    WHERE time_of_game.time_of_start = "2017-02-01 12:00:00"
      AND users.steamid = "1234567890123456";
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `payment_for_joining` 
AFTER INSERT ON `signed`
FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE users  
    SET users.credit = users.credit-1
    WHERE users.user_id = NEW.player
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't allow you to update the table because it's already being read by the `INSERT INTO.. SELECT` query that invokes this trigger.

An alternative way would be to disable the trigger and update the users table separately, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO signed (time_of_start, player)
SELECT time_of_game_id, users.user_id FROM time_of_game, users
WHERE time_of_game.time_of_start="2017-02-01 12:00:00"
AND users.steamid="1234567890123456";

UPDATE users join time_of_game SET users.credit = users.credit-1
where time_of_game.time_of_start="2017-02-01 12:00:00"
AND users.steamid="1234567890123456";
```

You can add a join column with `ON` clause if there is any column that links these two tables.

Comment: Yep, I was just hoping I can do this 2 operations with only one request/query. But I'm gonna take a tip from the more experienced programmer, I use your solution :) Thanks

Comment: Guessed so. Then whats the use of nice triggers if we can use our application code to do things? Just asking for Mysql writers. I will also do my own after-insert routines in my php code. And I will comment on my table description what is going on after insert.