# Mysql trigger update time

Tags: mysql, sql-update, database-trigger

I trying to after update table, update new update_time. Whats my wrong?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_update AFTER UPDATE ON urunler
    FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
            IF NEW.adi != OLD.adi THEN
                UPDATE urunler SET update_time=now();
            END IF;
        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

getting error

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'urunler' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

SOLVED WITH "BEFORE" not AFTER...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1442 - Can't update table '\*' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537750/1442-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-already)

Answer (score 0):

To apply a DML operation on the same table may raise mutating table error.

Rather, replace `UPDATE urunler SET update_time=now();` with `SET new.update_time = now();`

where `[old/new].update_time` expression represents a column within that table.